# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'show' using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a 3d figure but i get this error(it's not the complete code)

```
...
...
X = pca1.transform(d1)
fig2 = plot.figure(1,figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig2.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],X[:,2])
X.show()
```

Calling x.show()

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'show'
```

How can I draw it?

Comment: What about `plot.show()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X` is a numpy array, `type(X) == numpy.ndarray`. The error tells you that numpy arrays do not have a `show` method; which is expected, since it wouldn't be clear how to show them anyways.

For visualization you use `matplotlib.pyplot`.

If pyplot is imported like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` you can show all plots created with pyplot via

```
plt.show()
```

Inside interactive sessions you may also show a figure. In this case,

```
fig2.show()
```